# Can you deploy contracts to the mainnet with remix.ethereum?

Tags: remix, mainnet

As the title. Is it possible to deploy your .sol directly to the mainnet with e.g. MetaMask?

What options do I pick in remix 'deploy' to do this?

Once it is deployed, what is the simplest way of interacting with it? I know I should be able to do so through Remix site itself, but what about on a different browser/computer with a different MM account? E.g. if I want my friend to be able to test it from their computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do pretty much everything with Remix.

[Run & Deploy](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/udapp.html) - to run / make calls

[Deploying a Contract](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_deploy.html)

[This guide](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-remix-and-metamask-to-deploy-smart-contracts-on-the-rsk-testnet-zt393xfz) is helpful for reference regarding mainnet deployment
(simply choose it instead of testnet)

[Here](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import.html#import-buttons-on-the-remix-home-tab) is how to use remix collaboratively (github, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share your code with a friend, the quickest way would be to check your code into a repository like in Github, and then have your friend pull the code from their into their own remix environment. There is an article here on [dGIT](https://medium.com/remix-ide/github-in-remix-ide-356de378f7da) which lets you use Github inside of your Remix IDE.
The same approach can also work with a different browser using a different wallet, once you checkout the code from Github inside the Remix IDE environment in that browser it will be the same code.

Remember as well that Remix is just tooling. Once you have the Smart Contract code (the .sol file(s)) you can use other tooling to deploy your contracts as well if you prefer.
Examples below

- [Deploy using Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html)
- [Deploying using Truffle](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations.html)
- [Deploying using Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/deploy.html)
- [Deploying using the Solidity compiler](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/using-the-compiler.html)

There are other tooling of course, and each one of these including those linked above would require some pre-work in setting up the tooling environment to enable the deployment, but Remix IDE is great for getting started.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You ***can deploy to main-net using remix***,
After deploying you will see that ***remix provides a simple UI to interact with your contract functions***,
If you want a friend to then also test it, you can send him code ( through GitHub or any other media ) have him compile it in remix, ***then have him use the option
" At address " instead of deploy so you both can then interact with same contract***.

For testing purposes you can also do the same on test-net like Rinkeby.
And ***better testing is done though hardhat and mocha testing***, you can read all about it on [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts) official documentation